# What are class skills in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, class

Stupid question, but what exactly are class skills in the Pathfinder RPG? 
I believe it means I get one "free" skill rank in that class, am I right in this assumption?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You get a +3 bonus *if* you have put ranks a [Class Skill](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Class-Skills):

> In addition, each class has a number of favored skills, called class skills. It is easier for your character to become more proficient in these skills, as they represent part of his professional training and constant practice. **You gain a +3 bonus on all class skills that you put ranks into.** If you have more than one class and both grant you a class skill bonus, these bonuses do not stack.

Emphasis added.

Comment: Drat your faster fingers!  I was typing that!

Comment: The *story* aspect implication of "class skills" are: these are the skills that your class background indicates you have an aptitude towards using. As a member of that heroic class, they're part of your schtick. Therefore, when you put ranks in those skills (you have spent time practicing that skill), your *natural role in the ongoing story gives you a bump*. As this is a flat plus, the bump pays off much more in the early stage of your character's career than it does later.