# Pathfinder: Does the +3 Bonus count as ranks in itself, or just a bonus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

I have a simple, yet complicated question regarding skill ranks and the initial trained bonus of +3. My question arose when one of my players stated that he was a Pale Master at level 5 because he had 8 ranks in Religion and qualified for the rest of the prerequisites. However, I am under the impression that you can only put a number of ranks in a skill that does not exceed total hit dice. The player then stated that he was able to get 8 ranks in Religion because of the +3 bonus. My question is: Does the +3 actually count as ranks even though they can exceed the total hit dice, or do they just count as a bonus that would fall under 'Misc Mod' on the character sheet?

Comment: Hi Lost Echo, welcome to RPG.StackExchange!  Please take a look at the [About] page.  I've closed this excellent questions as duplicate because it's been asked before.

Answer (score 3):

**No.** Only Ranks count as ranks, no other bonuses apply for qualification for "rank" pre-requisites.

The +3 bonus itself is a [bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Class-Skills) not a skill rank.

> In addition, each class has a number of favored skills, called class
>   skills. It is easier for your character to become more proficient in
>   these skills, as they represent part of his professional training and
>   constant practice. You gain a ***+3 bonus on all class skills*** that you
>   put ranks into. If you have more than one class and both grant you a
>   class skill bonus, these bonuses do not stack.

Note that it says +3 bonus, not +3 skill ranks.

So; Only the ranks themselves count, indeed you don't even get the +3 bonus until you have one rank itself.

See also this question: [What are class skills](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7271/what-are-class-skills-in-pathfinder)

Comment: Worth noting: for this exact reason, part of the conversion process for 3.5 to *Pathfinder* is to reduce the highest skill requirements on things by 3.